# How do I refresh a listview with text and image using BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, listview

I need a little help with refreshing my listview data.

I made a listview following [this](https://www.sanktips.com/2017/10/12/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-example/) tutorial.

Here it is:

### ListAdapter.java:

```
package com.sanktips.customlistviewexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    private final String [] values;
    private final String [] numbers;
    private final int [] images;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, String [] values, String [] numbers, int [] images){
        //super(context, R.layout.single_list_app_item, utilsArrayList);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        this.numbers = numbers;
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return values.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {


        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.aNametxt);
            viewHolder.txtVersion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.aVersiontxt);
            viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appIconIV);

            result=convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result=convertView;
        }

        viewHolder.txtName.setText(values[position]);
        viewHolder.txtVersion.setText("Version: "+numbers[position]);
        viewHolder.icon.setImageResource(images[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {

        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtVersion;
        ImageView icon;

    }

}
```

### MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.sanktips.customlistviewexample;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    
    ListView lView;

    ListAdapter lAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

int[] images = {R.drawable.alpha, R.drawable.beta, R.drawable.cupcake, R.drawable.donut, R.drawable.eclair, R.drawable.froyo, R.drawable.gingerbread, R.drawable.honeycomb, R.drawable.icecreamsandwich, R.drawable.jellybean, R.drawable.kitkat, R.drawable.lollipop, R.drawable.marshmallow, R.drawable.nougat};

    String[] version = {"Android Alpha", "Android Beta", "Android Cupcake", "Android Donut", "Android Eclair", "Android Froyo", "Android Gingerbread", "Android Honeycomb", "Android Ice Cream Sandwich", "Android JellyBean", "Android Kitkat", "Android Lollipop", "Android Marshmallow", "Android Nougat"};

    String[] versionNumber = {"1.0", "1.1", "1.5", "1.6", "2.0", "2.2", "2.3", "3.0", "4.0", "4.1", "4.4", "5.0", "6.0", "7.0"};

        lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.androidList);

        lAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, version, versionNumber, images);

        lView.setAdapter(lAdapter);

        lView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, version[i]+" "+versionNumber[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

For some reason, when I call `notifySetDataChanged` on my list adapter, it's not working.

I also tried to recreate the adapter and it's not updating.

can someone help me how to refresh the listview correctly?

Comment: Where are you refreshing the adapter in your code? And are you updating any values in the array to call that refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, you have to provide a new data source. If you will call just `notifyDataSetChanged()` without any new data, your list will not refresh. So, before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` try to update the arrays data that you pass inside the constructor. But it's a good practice to add the update function inside the adapter. Also, you can use ArrayList instead of simple arrays.